# How to find why application cannot connect to SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql

Windows application is set to connect to the SQL Server using SQL Server authentication.
When I RDP to the box where the application resides and start the application, it successfully connects to the SQL Server.
When a customer runs the application on his desktop (he is on the network with the application box) and starts the application, connection fails (error. Server does not exist or access denied).
The customer can ping the SQL Server IP in his command prompt.
Yet, when I look at the error log on the SQL server I don't see the logs of his failure to connect.
What could be blocking his access to the SQL Server?

Comment: How is the application connecting to the SQL Server??  If ODBC, you need to create an ODBC connection to the SQL Server.

Comment: Yes, the application connects to the SQL using ODBC. And the ODBC connection is created; when I run the application it connects.

Comment: sorry, pressed Enter too soon. After I posted the initial message it occurred to me that the problem could be firewall.  I plan to ask the customer to look into this; if there is a firewall on his desktop that prevents the application from connecting.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to enable the TCP/IP protocol in SQL Server Configuration Manager - it's disabled by default.